# Minecraft: I have a good ping but can't connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I haven't found any duplicates on the "Questions that may already have your answer" section, so my apologies if I made a duplicate.

*Anyway*, it takes a while to connect to any Minecraft server with any ping, such as 40ms, 10ms, any ms really... Most of the time get a "Timed out" message or "Broken pipe". The slow connection only happens about 30 minutes into playing on multiplayer. If I try the next day, it does that 30 minute thing all over again. This laptop is running Ubuntu.

If I use a different computer on my same WiFi network, I get a perfect connection with no time outs *with the same exact ping*. This computer is running Windows.

I have done the research and no one else has had the same problem as me. The only last detail I can provide is that once the "Loggin in" text has gone away, it freezes there. I think that it takes forever to load the chunks. I'm not an expert on server stuff, but I know what's an error or not.

EDIT:
I'm on Minecraft 1.8. It's also been doing this with 1.8.4 and 1.8.6

Comment: Ping isn't really much of indicator of connection timeouts.

Comment: I just can't exactly determine the problem since it's doing this with all servers after a certain time period